# Trying Blazor deployment with github action on github pages (Action failed with "ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir)

Tags: c#, .net, github, blazor, github-actions

I've followed this tutorial https://www.meziantou.net/publishing-a-blazor-webassembly-application-to-github-pages.htm and during the process in github it produces this error:
[Error Github Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XkTS.png)

This is the github action file:

```yaml
name: 'Publish application'
on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        # Checkout the code
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2

        # Install .NET Core SDK
        - name: Setup .NET Core
          uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
          with:
            dotnet-version: 3.1.x

        # Run tests
        - name: Test
          run: dotnet test
        
        # DotNet restore
        - name: DotNet restore
          run: dotnet restore

        # Generate the website
        - name: Publish
          run: dotnet publish GSS.MyDotNetPortfolio.Presentation/GSS.MyDotNetPortfolio.Presentation.csproj --configuration Release

        # Publish the website
        - name: GitHub Pages action
          if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }} # Publish only when the push is on master
          uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3.6.1
          with:
            github_token: ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_TOKEN }}
            publish_branch: gh-pages
            publish_dir: bin/Release/netstandard2.1/publish/wwwroot
            allow_empty_commit: false
            keep_files: false
            force_orphan: true
            # TODO uncomment the following line if you have a custom domain name
            # cname: demo.meziantou.net
```

Here is my .gitignore file:
https://github.com/guillem-soler-suetta/GSS.MyDotNetPortfolio/blob/master/.gitignore

Any ideas? I've done some research and maybe the problem with the nugget packages used to build the project.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to share your github action script?

Comment: @Umair Edited the question with the file. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Could you provide us with a .gitignore file, if you have one? I'm presuming that it might have interfered with the action.

Comment: @Jaguar-515 Added the link to my .gitignore file, as you can see the project is public so you can see all the code.

Comment: Had a quick look - the error references `/GSS.MyDotNetPortfolio/GSS.MyDotNetPortfolio/..` but the source and the current ci.yml file have `GSS.MyDotNetPortfolio.Presentation` so you may have an old error.

Comment: @meziantou
The author of that blog is here. How can we get his attention to this?

Answer (score 1):

The error just says that your publishing directory does not exist. Check the correct location of it.

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
    github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    publish_dir: ./public
```

Please feel free to open your issue at the repository.

For more details, see the latest README here: [peaceiris/actions-gh-pages: GitHub Actions for GitHub Pages  Deploy static files and publish your site easily. Static-Site-Generators-friendly.](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages)

Answer (score 0):

```
name: gh-pages

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
    - name: Publish with dotnet
      run: dotnet publish **projectName/projectName.csproj** --configuration Release --output build
    - name: Deploy to Github Pages
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
      with:
        ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        BASE_BRANCH: master # The branch the action should deploy from.
        BRANCH: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
        FOLDER: build/wwwroot # The folder the action should deploy.
        SINGLE_COMMIT: true
```

change the project name to yours and try. lifted from a site, don't know if its okay to give attribution here. it worked for me.